# Swift passing array to function with return

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I need this array

```
self.values.append(value)
```

in order to append another array with the values from the array above^. Pretty much i need to pass one array to another function with the appended values.

```
 func updateChartValues() -> (LineChartDataSet) {

           self.recieveChartValues()

            var entries: [ChartDataEntry] = Array()

            for i in 0 ..< values.count {

                entries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(values[i]), data: UIImage(named: "icon", in: Bundle(for: self.classForCoder), compatibleWith: nil)))
```

How can I get these values that are appended from recieveChartValues() to updateChartValues? The main confusion is because they are appended from Firebase.

```
func recieveChartValues() {

        //Firebase Initialization
        var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        ref.child("general_room_index").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in
            print("error3")



            if let snaps = snap.value as? [Any]{
                for val in snaps {
                    if let value = val as? Int{
                        self.values.append(value)
                        //print(self.values)
                    }
                }
            }

        })

    }//retrive values func



func updateChartValues() -> (LineChartDataSet) {

       self.recieveChartValues()

        var entries: [ChartDataEntry] = Array()

        for i in 0 ..< values.count {

            entries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(values[i]), data: UIImage(named: "icon", in: Bundle(for: self.classForCoder), compatibleWith: nil)))

            print("Enetrie ", entries)



        }



        self.dataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: entries, label: "Bullish vs. Bearish")
        self.dataSet.mode = LineChartDataSet.Mode.cubicBezier


        return dataSet

    }
```

Comment: Since the Firebase task will complete asynchronously you will need to pass a closure to `recieveChartValues` and invoke that closure from the Firebase completion closure

Comment: could you show me an example how how to do that

Comment: I kind of understand completion and closeures Im just not sure how to implement them with these two functions i need an example to fully understand

Comment: Anyone? can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Paulw11 says, the crux is the asynchronous nature. If you just do

```
recieveChartValues()
updateChartValues()
```

`recieveChartValues()` runs (and returns immediately), then `updateChartValues()` runs (using `self.values` without the new value being appended), then the completion closure that appends the new value runs.

Either directly call `updateChartValues()` in the completion closure, like this:

```
ref.child("general_room_index").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in
    ...
    if let snaps = snap.value as? [Any] {
        for val in snaps {
            if let value = val as? Int{
                self.values.append(value)
                updateChartValues()
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Or add a closure parameter to `recieveChartValues()` and call that when you get a new value:

```
func recieveChartValues(_ completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    ...
    if let snaps = snap.value as? [Any] {
        for val in snaps {
            if let value = val as? Int{
                self.values.append(value)
                completion()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And call `recieveChartValues` like this:

```
recieveChartValues { self.updateChartValues() }
```

You can also add a parameter to the completion closure so you can pass the received value to it, if you are interested in that:

```
func recieveChartValues(_ completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    ...
            if let value = val as? Int{
                self.values.append(value)
                completion(value)
            }
    ...
}
```

Then your closure will be called with the new value:

```
recieveChartValues { newValue in
    print("Received \(newValue)")
    self.updateChartValues()
}
```